# Как поменять стили при наведении на div?

Tags: javascript

Приветствую!
Просьба помочь, у меня есть класс "parent", который содержит класс "children", хочу сделать, что бы при наведении на парент, мой чилдрен исчезал, вот мой код:

```
var parent = document.body.getElementsByClassName("parent");
var children = document.body.getElementsByClassName("children");
for( var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++){
    parent[i].onmouseover = function () {
        children[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

но при наведении у меня выскакивает ошибка: "Сannot read property 'style' of undefined at HTMLDivElement.parent.(anonymous function).onmouseover"

Заранее большое спасибо за помощь.

Comment: html код в студию!

Comment: думаю вы неправильно выбераете элементы, используете одинаковый индекс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблема в навешивание ивентхендлеров в данном случае, i всегда будет максимальным, то-есть будет равно parent.length, из-за этого children[i] всегда undefined

Вот кусок вроде рабочего кода:

```js
var p = document.body.getElementsByClassName("parent");
var c = document.body.getElementsByClassName("children");

for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    addEvent(p[i], i);
}

function addEvent(element, index) {        
    element.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
        document.body.getElementsByClassName("children")[index].style.display = "none";
    });
};
```

```html
   <div style="background-color:red" class="parent">
    parent 1
</div>
<div style="background-color:darkred" class="parent">
    parent 2
</div>

<div style="background-color:yellow" class="children">
    children 1
</div>
<div style="background-color:greenyellow" class="children">
    children 2
</div>
```

ПС: почитайте про замыкания

Если элементы все-же вложенные, то этот вариант будет получше :

```js
var p = document.body.getElementsByClassName("parent");

for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    p[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
        var children = this.getElementsByClassName("children");
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            children[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:red;padding:5%;" class="parent">
    parent 1

    <div style="background-color:yellow" class="children">
        children 1
    </div>

</div>
<div style="background-color:darkred;padding:5%;" class="parent">
    parent 2

    <div style="background-color:greenyellow" class="children">
        children 2
    </div>
</div>
```

сори что флужу, не удержался :)

Comment: зачем `var indx = index;`?

Comment: ну я думал что замыкание по другому не будет работать, но щасс вот засомневался и пойду смотреть...

Comment: согласен, работает и так ! спасибо за замечание !

Answer (score 3):

Почему не использовать просто CSS

```
.parent:hover .children{
display: none
}
```

Если он действительно лежит в паренте

Comment: Задание просто было именно через javascript